# Cambio de nombre columnas, con cambio de formato

Tags: r

la pregunta que tengo es algo enrevesada.

- Descargó datos de GEE, vienen con el formato que se puede ver al construir la tabla.
- Proceso para quedarme con la fecha y los últimos 4 dígitos que me indican de la banda que se trata.
- Pero aquí viene el problema, cuando quiero cambiar esta fecha de formato, primero a un formato normal, y después a día del año (que posteriormente modifico mediante una condicional para que se quede día respecto a una fecha, 2017-11-01 en este caso, es decir, el 2017-11-01 sería el 1), pues cuando hago esto el sufijo con el índice (_NDVI y _SAVI en el ejemplo), se me va.

[image: Ejemplo problema]

- Lo que buscaría sería que se me quedará una cosa así:

[image: Ejemplo Solución]

En el caso de que fuera uno solo, pues añadía luego un sufijo y solucionado, pero:

- Son varios, no solo 2, al menos 5 o 6
- Son muchas columnas de 200 a 1000, por lo que cambiarlos a mano es inviable
- Lo ideal sería hacerlo de manera automática, que se guarde el sufijo de alguna manera y luego me lo pusiera una vez procesado los datos, pero a unas malas creo que la solución sería un bucle que le ponga a la x NDVI, a la x+1 SAVI, a la x+3 EVI, y luego en bucle.

---

```
#Creamos el dataframe con el que vamos a trabajar
id <- c(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_NDVI <- c(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_SAVI <- c(0.16, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_NDVI <- c(0.17, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_SAVI <- c(0.18, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)

pointsExtractCoords <- data.frame(id, X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_NDVI, 
                                  X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_SAVI, 
                                  X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_NDVI,
                                  X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_SAVI)

#Contamos el numero de columnas y lo guardamos en la variable x

x <- ncol(pointsExtractCoords)

#Extraemos la parte del nombre de las columnas que nos interesa, en este caso la fecha
#Podríamos extraer también la parte final concatenando la, para quedarnos con el tipo de indice

nombres_col = names(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x]
nuevas_col = paste0(substr(nombres_col, 2, 9), # extraer del segundo dígito al noveno
                    "_", # concatenarle un "_"
                    substr(nombres_col, nchar(nombres_col) - 3, nchar(nombres_col))) # Extraer desde el antepenúltimo al ultimo digito

names(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x] = nuevas_col

#Pasamos las fechas a un formato de fácil lectura para otros comandos

fechas = names(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x]
nuevas_fechas = paste0(ymd(fechas))
names(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x] = nuevas_fechas

#Pasamos de fecha a día del año

dias = paste0(yday(nuevas_fechas))
names(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x] = dias

#Una vez tenemos los días del año, teniendo en cuenta la fecha de siembra, calculamos los días
# desde la siembra

# Extraemos los números de los nombres de las variables

nombre1 <- as.numeric(colnames(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x])

# Generamos una copia que servirá de ayuda

nombre2 <- nombre1

# A aquellos que sean mayores que la fecha de siembra les restamos los días pertinentes

nombre2[nombre1>305] <- nombre2[nombre1>305] - 305

# A aquellos que sean menores porque se encuentran ya en el siguiente año, le sumamos
#los días pertinentes

nombre2[nombre1<305] <- nombre2[nombre1<305] + 60

# Asignamos nombre2 a los nombres de las columnas

colnames(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x] <- nombre2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes algo de experiencia usando los paquetes de `tidyverse` puedes implementar algo bastante más conciso:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1] %>% 
  str_match('^X(\\d+).*(.{4})$') %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(dias = ymd(V2)-ymd('2017-11-01'),
         new_col = paste(V3,dias, sep='_')) %>%
  select(V1, new_col)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  V1                                           new_col
  <chr>                                        <chr>  
1 X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_NDVI NDVI_4 
2 X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_SAVI SAVI_4 
3 X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_NDVI NDVI_14
4 X20171115T110321_20171115T110620_T30SUG_SAVI SAVI_14
```

Explicación:

- Tomamos los nombres de todas las columnas menos la primera `names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1]`
- Con expresiones regulares extraemos las dos cadenas que nos interesan: `str_match('^X(\\d+).*(.{4})$')`
- Convertimos todo a un `tibble`
- Calculamos los días a partir de una fecha de inicio: `ymd(V2)-ymd('2017-11-01')`
- concatenamos días con el código capturado

Si necesitas un vector para luego renombrar las columnas:

```
names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1] %>% 
  str_match('^X(\\d+).*(.{4})$') %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(dias = ymd(V2)-ymd('2017-11-01'),
         new_col = paste(V3,dias, sep='_')) %>%
  select(new_col) %>% 
  c() -> nuevas_columnas
```

**Importante**: esto es generalizable a todas las columnas que mantengan el formato esperado.

Comment: Esta solución, es realmente ideal, pero me da error la función ymd

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `dias = ymd(V2) - ymd("2017-11-01")`.
Caused by error in `ymd()`:
! could not find function "ymd"

Comment: Como ya la estabas usando imagine que tenías cargado `lubridate`, prueba agregar al comienzo `library(lubridate)`

Comment: La tenía cargada, pero he reiniciado para instalar tidyverse, y se ha ido, error jeje
Y los nombres me los ha cargado en una lista, pero vaya unlist y ya están cambiados, muchas gracias.
Ha sido una solución más que perfecta, porque me ha solucionado poblemas que no había planteado

Comment: Siento molestar, pero al hacer en el dataframe, me da este error:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’

Función todo perfecto pero no me lo vuelca en la lista/vector

Comment: Normalmente ese error es por que algún paquete sobreescribió la función `select`, prueba modificar la llamada por `dplyr::select()`

Comment: El dataframe, tiene valores NA, alguna manera de que los seleccione? Que esa funcion no los selecciona

Comment: Me estás preguntando por otro tema no? Si es así, te sugiero que armes otra pregunta, aún así, si lo que me estás preguntando es acerca de como filtrar datos, en `dplyr` existe el verbo `filter()`

Comment: No no, me refiero al mismo tema, que me he explicado muy mal. Al aplicar la función select() del paquete de dplyr, me da error porque el dataframe contiene valores nulos. Existe alguna otra función que utilizar, o alguna manera de indicar que los seleccione igualmente? Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: A ver, podrías agregar la salida completa de `dput(names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1])` ?

Comment: Esto es lo que me aparece, cuando utilizo select:

Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Cuando hago el dput(names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1]), me aparecen todos los nombres iniciales de las columnas:

c("X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_EEVI", "X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_NDVI", 
"X20171105T110231_20171105T110231_T30SUG_NDWI")

Pongo los 3 primeros que son 240.

Comment: He seguido dándole vueltas y la verdad es que no hay ningún valor nulo en los nombres de las columnas, no se porque aparece esto, osea en el resto del dataframe, si que hay (he tratado a eliminarnos para probar, y sigue dando error) que no tendría nada que ver (pero por probar)

Comment: Columnas nulas no puede haber,lo que sí tal vez exista alguna que no siga el patrón que mencionaste, sin ver las columnas completas no puedo decirte mucho más,  revisa la extracción de los datos `names(pointsExtractCoords)[-1] %>% str_match('^X(\\d+).*(.{4})$')`, la segunda columna siempre debe ser un cadena convertible a fecha y no debería haber ningún NA.

Answer (score 0):

Pues me respondo a mi mismo, ya que he encontrado la solución al problema que comentaba en los comentarios con Patricio.

Lo que he hecho ha sido utilizar pull() para extraer la columna que me interesaba del tbl, así también me ahorro la línea de convertir de lista a vector que necesitaba con select().

Muchas gracias de nuevo Patricio, tu respuesta ha sido sublime.

````
  str_match('^X(\\d+).*(.{4})$') %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(dias = ymd(V2)-ymd('2017-11-01'),
         new_col = paste(V3,dias, sep='_')) %>% 
  pull(new_col) -> new_col
  
x <- ncol(pointsExtractCoords)
colnames(pointsExtractCoords)[2:x] <- new_col```
````